# insert date/time stamp and user name or email on google sheets method

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to google scripts app, but I would like to add to this script the following:

When an insert into "sheet B" is performed it also inserts the date/time (Now) in to column 4 and also any user detail into a cell column 5. So user name, email address, something that is user-related so I know who did it.

```
   function transferdata() {

var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.alert(
  '***          ATTENTION          ***', 
  'Do you want to "SAVE" this information on the "Sheet B" tab',
  ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if (result == ui.Button.YES) {

  var tab1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet A");

  var Name = tab1.getRange("B1").getValue();
  var Group = tab1.getRange("B3").getValue();
  var System = tab1.getRange("B5").getValue();


  var tab2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet B");
  var lr = tab2.getLastRow() + 1;

  tab2.getRange(lr, 1).setValue(Name);
  tab2.getRange(lr, 2).setValue(Group);
  tab2.getRange(lr, 3).setValue(System);


  tab1.getRange("B1").clearContent();
  tab1.getRange("B3").clearContent();
  tab1.getRange("B5").clearContent();


  ui.alert ('Information was successfully SAVED on the DATABASE tab');
   } else {
     ui.alert ('The information "NOT" has been saved!');

 }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Where have you tried to do this yourself in your code?

Comment: Not very successful and am learning Google scripts (all of 2 weeks) if MS then would have it done by now. I have tried to use     var now = new Date(); and then insert with  tab2.getRange(lr, 4).setValue(date); so any help would appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this part of your code

In column 1 will be the email and in column 2 the date

```
tab2.getRange(lr, 1).setValue([Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()]);
tab2.getRange(lr, 2).setValue(new Date());
tab2.getRange(lr, 3).setValue(Name);
tab2.getRange(lr, 4).setValue(Group);
tab2.getRange(lr, 5).setValue(System);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if(ss.getName()=="sheet B"){
    var row=e.range.getRow();
    ss.getRange(row, 4).setValue(new Date());
        ss.getRange(row, 5).setValue(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
  }
}
```

But keep in mind that the username will be only retrieved for users of your domain.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - however this does not appear to be working for me, however, that could be where i am putting the code. Can you confirm where in script editor this should be positioned . under the original script, new script?

Comment: It is a separate function, you can either put it in the same .gs file under or above `function transferdata(){...}` or in a separate .gs file - just not within `function transferdata(){...}`. You have to run the function once manually before it starts triggering automatically `onEdit`.

Comment: Ok, it was a capital issue on the sheet name 'Sheet' vs 'sheet' however this works nearly for what I need. However I need it to put the entry against the line which is inserted and not just the top row. To help explain. This is a data entry form, which once some completes the entry goes in the next empty row in Sheet B. So if it can be entered on the same line as the entry from the Sheet A, would be what I need. Also any way of not just the domain name, but also the name before the @ cheers

Comment: I slightly modified the code in my answer, it should do now what you asked for. However, retrieving the email of the active user is bound to restrictions, see documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session Basically, the active user can be retrieved if "the developer belongs to the same G Suite domain as the user.".